# Unable to install bcrypt on Ubuntu on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm

On an Ubuntu Server 18.04 on an Amazon EC2 instance, I had an error when doing sudo npm install bcrypt.
The version trying to install is "bcrypt": "^5.0.1" on my package.json

Here's the error I had:

```
> bcrypt@5.0.1 install /home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@14.16.0 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1037-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1037-aws
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm WARN isequi@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN isequi@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: ` EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/prod/back/node_modules/bcrypt/build'` is the actual error here. Your user doesn't have permission to write to the node_modules directory.

Comment: @jordanm after create the post I saw the fail.. strange because I am running with sudo and I have all the permissions.. I could install using sudo npm install bcrypt --unsafe-perm